# TF400069 You must install the "Client Tools Connectivity"

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have a small issue that is driving me crazy.
I'm trying to install TFS 2015 on a VM with Windows Server 2012 R2 and SQL SERVER 2016.

Everything is ok but my on Analysis Services Settings I get an error.

> TF400069:  When your configuration includes Reporting features on a
>   remote machine, you must install the "Client Tools Connectivity"
>   feature from SQL Server.

As you can see on the following screenshot "Client Tools Connectivity" is installed.
Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: TFS won't necessarily support 2016 since it only came out a week ago.

Comment: This crossed my mind...I'll try it tomorrow with 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the [TFS requirements and compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements), the supported SQL Server version is:

- SQL Server 2014
- SQL Server 2012 (minimum SP1)

SQL Server 2016 is not in the list yet. You need to use compatible SQL Server version.

Comment: TFS 2015 Update 3 now supports SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Installing Update 3 solved this error for me.  I am using SQL Server 2016.